# Issue about colour link

Tags: email, hyperlink

My problem is that on the "Windows Mail" mail client, the default one on Windows. The text of my buttons appear in blue as hyperlinks.
Here's my code, along with the mso command for compatibility.

Thanks in advance.

`<!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;color:#ffffff !important;" arcsize="100%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FA5528"> <w:anchorlock/> <center> <![endif]--> <p  class="littlebutton" style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;  text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF !important;"> <a href="https://forms.office.com/e/P3eEN9XXNv" style="background-color:#FA5528; border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; color:#ffffff !important; display:inline-block; font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;font-weight:bold; line-height:40px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:250px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">INSERT TEXT HERE</a> </p> <!--[if mso]> </center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]-->`